# Can't get the Dropbox API PHP Tutorial to work

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am playing with the `Dropbox api` but can't get past the first step of making it work.  Any help would be great!  I did try to do a thorough search on Google for my problem with no luck.

Tutorial Link -> https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php

PHP Version: 5.3.8

I am getting an error on this line:

```
use \Dropbox as dbx;
```

It is throwing this error: Parse error: syntax error,

```
 unexpected T_USE in . . .
```

My code is extremely simple so far:

```
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Move the "use" declaration to the top of the file and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Nothing changed sir.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is syntactically correct, but the `use` declaration has certain restraints that you need to follow.

Ensure you're `use` statements are being processed before any other code is run bar the required `require_once`.

```
<?php
require_once 'dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php';
use \Dropbox as dbx;
?>
```

This will (and does) parse correctly as the entire contents of the script.